# How to avoid errors in multiple insertion with unique stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I wonder how is it possible to manage transaction in c# code..
I have to do multiple insertion of same object with unique storedprocedure.
So I have to launch the same stored procedure with same parameters multiple times.

But if a problem appear in the process (lost connection,...) I don't want just a part of insertions done and the rest failed, I want all the insertion cancelled.
So I would like a SQLtransaction but within the application code because a can't change database.

I hope i'm clear enough and hope somebody can help me and push me on the good way..
Tx

Comment: http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/040914.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call BeginTransaction on the SqlConnection before starting the work, and then CommitTransaction (or RollbackTransaction) at the end.

See [MSDN reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx) for example.

Comment: Tx a lot for response, Do i close connection for rollback and commit? Or It's include in the operations?

Comment: @bAN - Yep, clean up the connection as you normally would

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`BeginTransaction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx#Y900) method (and the relevant subsequent methods) to perform transactions from code.  That link has an example on how to do it.

Example:

```
db.BeginTransaction("myTransaction");
try
{
    // all your code here.  If anything goes awry, throw an exception

    // all good, commit it.
    db.CommitTransaction();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // undo everything we just did
    db.RollbackTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SqlConnection` class (`IDbConnection` interface) has a method `BeginTrasaction` take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx).